# Drupal 7 Entity Reference and content type field display

Tags: drupal-7, contenttype, entityreference

I have successfully created an Entity Reference as one of my content type fields. I am using the Select List as my widget type. The content of the Select List defaults to the node title. This is problematic in my case and I would like to display different field content of that node. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an entity reference field in the field settings you can specify that it uses an "entity reference view" to create the list of options.

So in Views, create a new view that outputs the field you want for the Entity type you want. Set the display type to be "Entity reference" (you may need to install the [Entity Reference view Widget](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) module)

then in the the field settings for your field set it to use that view.

Comment: In the content type fields UI I would like to have a List (txt) yet when I use views (along with Entity Reference) it doesn't have that format.

Comment: I also tried the  'Entity Reference view Widget', I was able to list view fields using check-boxes. It's listed under alpha version so not sure how stable it is? It was throwing a bunch of errors so I uninstalled it.